# What will be the solution of this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

What will be the solution of the equation.
$(x^2+m^2)\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial(x^2+m^2)}+(x+m)\frac{\partial y}{\partial (x+m)}+(x^2+m^2-n^2)=0$ where $m$ may be a constant

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(x^2+m^2)\dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial^2(x^2+m^2)}+(x+m)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial(x+m)}+x^2+m^2-n^2=0$

$(x^2+m^2)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial(x^2+m^2)}\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial(x^2+m^2)}\right)+(x+m)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}+x^2+m^2-n^2=0$

$\dfrac{x^2+m^2}{2x}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{1}{2x}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)+(x+m)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}+x^2+m^2-n^2=0$

$\dfrac{x^2+m^2}{2x}\left(\dfrac{1}{2x}\dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}-\dfrac{1}{2x^2}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)+(x+m)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}+x^2+m^2-n^2=0$

$\dfrac{x^2+m^2}{4x^2}\dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}+\left(x+m-\dfrac{x^2+m^2}{4x^3}\right)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=n^2-m^2-x^2$

$\dfrac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}+\left(\dfrac{4x^2(x+m)}{x^2+m^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\dfrac{4x^2(n^2-m^2-x^2)}{x^2+m^2}$